# Is working as a software developer for a meat supplier permissible?

Tags: halal-haram, work, meat, software

Can I work as a software developer for a company which sells beef and lamb meat? This company doesn't sell pork, but their meat is not slaughtered in an Islamic way. They also sell pet food.

My role would be designing software for their logistic head office.

Comment: I can't see why one should be concerned. Why do you think working for a meat supplier could be a problem (not allowed)?

Comment: Because Meat is not slaughtered in Islamic ways. I have seen fatwas saying that it is not allowed to work for a shop who sells haram things like Alcohol and Pork or lottery tickets.

Comment: Steve, every non halal thing is not haram. If your work doesn't encourage non halal food you should go on. This is my personal thought, we shall wait for more authentic answer.

Comment: I have been advised not to work for them.

Comment: @SteveDyson I also agree that you should go on. By this logic almost every job becomes haram. For an accountant doing tax refunds (which can/will be used  to buy alcohol and pork), for grocery workers selling grapes which will be used to ferment and create alcohol, or someone selling knives which may end up as  a murder weapon. You are just a software developer for a business, and that's the end of that.

Comment: Are the animals slaughtered by hand (halal) or machine (haram). If Hand, is it Christian/Jewish hands (halal) or not (haram)?

Answer (score 1):

as i know, trading with disbelievers is allowed, and your case is like that, you are like making service to them, and your work does not involve selling haram food, though, you design software, it is for general logistic and you do not make front page images and slogans selling food... logistic soft can also be used for other purposes... and you are not paid by haram food but by money... i have (also...) heard (the) idea that money earned by haram is (itself) haram but i do not know any proofs for that yet now...